# getting error in AWS comprehend custom entity recognition : DOCUMENT_CORPUS_SIZE_LESS_THEN_MINIMUM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-comprehend

I am creating a model in custom entity recognizer and getting below error
: document corpus size is less then minimum requirement:5120 byte

My training entity list csv file size is 7kb(which is more than 5120 byte) and test data file is 5 kb

Answer (score 1):

Got the resolution.
There is two thing
first is the entity list
The second is test data (my test data was very short)
I used ONE_DOCUMENT_PER_LINE mode and in sample data file added more data to test.